# How to use zip4j to extract an zip file with password protection

Tags: java, passwords, unzip

I am trying to unzip a zipfile with password protection. I know there is a java library named "zip4j" that could help me. But I am failing to open the zip4j website to see the tutorial.

I had download zip4j library with another mirror but I don't know how to use it. Is there anyone that could paste example code for using zip4j unzip password protection zip file?

[zip4j website](http://www.lingala.net)

thanks so much!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the following and make sure you are using the most recent Zip4j library (1.3.1):

```
String source = "folder/source.zip";
String destination = "folder/source/";
String password = "password";

try {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
    if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
        zipFile.setPassword(password);
    }
    zipFile.extractAll(destination);
} catch (ZipException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you enter the wrong password the program is going to create an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a file game.zip in Downloads folder in android phone and we are extracting it with the password given below:

```
String unzipFileAddress = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS "/Game.zip";
String filePassword = "2222"; // password of the file
String destinationAddress = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Game";

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(unzipFileAddress, filePassword.toCharArray());
        
try {
     zipFile.extractAll(destinationAddress);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // if crashes print the message or Toast
}
```

Add in dependencies in build Gradle (app level) before doing it

```
dependencies{
 implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.6.4'
} // for lastest version check the link below
```

Make sure you have storage permission, these silly mistakes can take your valuable time

```
// Add in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Make sure your zip file is not a corrupt file by extracting it manually.

If you want to do some complex work with compression, you should take help from here: https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j

Answer (score 1):

## Full Implementation to Zip/Unzip a Folder/File with [zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j)

---

Add [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/2.9.0) to your build manager. Or, download the latest JAR file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j) and [add it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-jar-file-to-classpath-in-java/) to your project build path. The `class` bellow can compress and extract any file or folder with or without password protection-

```
import java.io.File;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.util.Zip4jConstants;
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;  

public class Compressor {
    public static void zip (String targetPath, String destinationFilePath, String password) {
        try {
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
            parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

            if (password.length() > 0) {
                parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
                parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
                parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
                parameters.setPassword(password);
            }
                
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destinationFilePath);
                
            File targetFile = new File(targetPath);
            if (targetFile.isFile()) {
                zipFile.addFile(targetFile, parameters);
            } else if (targetFile.isDirectory()) {
                zipFile.addFolder(targetFile, parameters);
            } else {
                //neither file nor directory; can be symlink, shortcut, socket, etc.
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
    public static void unzip(String targetZipFilePath, String destinationFolderPath, String password) {
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(targetZipFilePath);
            if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                zipFile.setPassword(password);
            }
            zipFile.extractAll(destinationFolderPath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    /**/ /// for test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String targetPath = "target\\file\\or\\folder\\path";
        String zipFilePath = "zip\\file\\Path"; 
        String unzippedFolderPath = "destination\\folder\\path";
        String password = "your_password"; // keep it EMPTY<""> for applying no password protection
            
        Compressor.zip(targetPath, zipFilePath, password);
        Compressor.unzip(zipFilePath, unzippedFolderPath, password);
    }/**/
}
```

---

For more detailed usage, see [here](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j#usage).

If you are working on android, then please make sure that you have added storage permission in the manifest file.