# How to check if a zip file is password protected using java?

Tags: java, encryption, zip4j

I want to check whether a zip file is password protected or not using java? The zip file is AES_256 encrypted.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174851/how-to-use-zip4j-to-extract-an-zip-file-with-password-protection?