# how to check given inputstream(zip file) is password protected or not using java?

Tags: java, zip, password-protection

I have inputstream of zip file , want to check if this inputstream is password protected or not . I have gone through this [How to use zip4j to extract an zip file with password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174851/how-to-use-zip4j-to-extract-an-zip-file-with-password-protection).

```
String source = "folder/source.zip";
String destination = "folder/source/";
String password = "password";

try {
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
    zipFile.setPassword(password);
}
zipFile.extractAll(destination);
} catch (ZipException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in this website above solution is given . but i do not have file or file path location. i have only inputstream of zip file can someone tell me how i can check whether given inputstream (zip file) is password protected or not. thanks in advance.

Comment: If it allows you to open an `InputStream` on it in the first place when it's password-protected, my guess is that's it's likely to throw an exception if you try to read it. Did you try that?

Comment: yes i am able to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think there is a library that will do exactly what you want.

- zip4j `ZipFile` can only open a `File` or a `String` pathname.
- Java SE `ZipFile` can only open a `File` or a `String` pathname ... and doesn't support encrypted entries.
- Java SE `ZipInputStream` does support an `InputStream`, but doesn't support encrypted entries.
- Apache Commons `ZipFile` does support seekable input streams (and channels), but not `InputStream`.  And it doesn't understand encrypted entries.
- Apache Commons `ZipInputStream` works with any `InputStream` but it doesn't understand encrypted entries.

---

So what are the options?

The simplest option would be to copy the `InputStream` contents to a temporary file and then use zip4j `ZipFile` as per the code in your question.   When you are finished, delete the temporary file.

In theory, you ought to be able to use Java SE `ZipInputStream` and scan the entries to check the `FileHeader` for each file.  (Bit zero of the "general purpose bit" field tells you if the file is encrypted.)  The problem is that `ZipEntry` doesn't expose the information.

However, Apache's `ZipInputStream` class (which can read an `InputStream`!), exposes the general purpose bit field.  So this would provide a way to test if any of the files in the ZIP is encrypted.  If that is all you need, then you have another possible option.